# XML parsing error: "not well formed at..."

Tags: android

I'm getting an error parsing XML: `not well formed at the "Android:hint..."`

I've checked and copied and pasted even from the site and still get the same error.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText android:id=@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You missed a quotation mark at `<EditText android:id= <- here`

Comment: put the open quote at - <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message" but it hasn't cleared up that error.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the EditText. The " is missing near android:id

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
```

Comment: disregard.  cleared up.  Thank you guys for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

This works: (What Daniel said above - the quote was missing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```